# -webkit-transform: incremental reposition with += operator not working

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to incrementally reposition an element by setting the `-webkit-transform` property to `+=200px`

But it doesn't work. I'm missing something, but don't know what.

- **http://jsfiddle.net/yVSDC/**

Clicking the div is supposed to move it further down by 200px everytime.

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't work like that, and jQuery doesn't pull that data out so you can do it like that.

You'd need to read the value, add `200` and then reset it.

```
var getTranslatedY = function (element) {
    var transform = element.css("transform") || element.css("-webkit-transform") || element.css("-moz-transform");

    if (transform == "none") {
        return 0;
    }

    return parseInt((transform.match(/^matrix\(.*?(-?[\d.]+)\)$/) || [])[1]) || 0;
};

$('#m').on(
    'click',
    function () {
    var element = $(this);
         element
         .css('-webkit-transform',
              "translateY(" + (getTranslatedY(element) + 200) + "px)");
    });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gTKvq/).

Comment: well, it works with things like marginLeft, so why wouldn't it also work with translate?

Comment: @tim Because `margin-left`'s value is, for example, `42px`. `transform`'s value is `translate(42px)`. It would need to be a lot smarter in order to parse that. You could probably set it up as a hook in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
var step = 200;
$('body').on('click', "#m", function(){
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform','translateY('+ step +'px)');
    step = step+200;
});
```

And instead `-webkit-transform:translateY(100px);` in CSS you can set `margin-top: 100px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/yVSDC/28/

Comment: Its possible do it on hover instead click?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the Current `webkit-transform` value and increment it. Alternative Solution is ustin the `top` CSS Property

You can try this (it's free): http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Sample Code:

```
$('.box').transition({ x: '200px' });
$('.box').transition({ y: '200px' });
$('.box').transition({ x: '200px', y: '200px' });
```