# .click only works once with .css

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am trying to make a custom slider.

What I want:
Everytime I click on ".c-button" I want the ".belt" class to shift -290px.

What is Happening:
The ".belt" only translates on the first click and every click afterwards does nothing. Help?

```
$(".c-button").click(function() {
    $(".belt").css({"transform":"translateX(-290px)"});
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194728/jquery-click-event-works-only-once

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a duplicate. There is no evidence that event delegation is required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Draco18s mentioned, you're transforming the translation of an element by a specific amount, relative to its original position. Each time you click a button, the translation is set to the same value. You'll need to *increment* the `translateX` value, instead.

One method is to read the current value and increment it, as [shown by Draco18s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209409/click-only-works-once-with-css#answer-34209493).
Another method is to store the value in a variable, as [shown by Miljan Puzović](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914712/webkit-transform-incremental-reposition-with-operator-not-working#answer-15915130).

---

An alternative method is to use CSS [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) rather than `transform`. You can more easily increment the value of `left` with the [addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) (`+=`) operator, without storing or parsing the current value.

```js
$(".c-button").click(function() {
  $(".belt").css({
    "left": "+=20"
  });
});
```

```css
.belt {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #F00;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="belt"></div>
<button class="c-button">click</button>
<button class="c-button">click</button>
<button class="c-button">click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not how the CSS transform properties work.  This sets the current transform to exactly 290 pixels from where the element normally sits.

In order to increase the translation by an increasing amount, you will need to *read the current value*, then parse it to an integer, then add (well, subtract) 290 pixels, and then perform the translation based on that value.

```
$(".belt").click(function(){
  var posX = parseInt($(".belt").css('transform').split(/,/)[4]);
  posX -= 290;
  console.log(posX);
  $(".belt").css('transform','translatex('+posX+'px)');
});
```

Comment: still lost, can you show me the implementation you are suggesting using my code snippet?